# Tensorflow - Am I restoring the model correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have the following code which is working (no errors). My question is just am I **restoring** the model correctly? Especially that I cannot see any output for the statement `print(v_)`.

So, I'm trying to know if I'm doing the following correct:

1. Restoring the model
2. Using that restored model

   import tensorflow as tf

   ```
   data, labels = cifar_tools.read_data('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Testing')

   x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 150 * 150])
   y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

   w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 64]))
   b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

   w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 64, 64]))
   b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))

   w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([38*38*64, 1024]))
   b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))

   w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 2]))
   b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))

   def conv_layer(x,w,b):
       conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,w,strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
       conv_with_b = tf.nn.bias_add(conv,b)
       conv_out = tf.nn.relu(conv_with_b)
       return conv_out

   def maxpool_layer(conv,k=2):
       return tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1,k,k,1], strides=[1,k,k,1], padding='SAME')

   def model():
       x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 150, 150, 1])

       conv_out1 = conv_layer(x_reshaped, w1, b1)
       maxpool_out1 = maxpool_layer(conv_out1)
       norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(maxpool_out1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
       conv_out2 = conv_layer(norm1, w2, b2)
       norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv_out2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)
       maxpool_out2 = maxpool_layer(norm2)

       maxpool_reshaped = tf.reshape(maxpool_out2, [-1, w3.get_shape().as_list()[0]])
       local = tf.add(tf.matmul(maxpool_reshaped, w3), b3)
       local_out = tf.nn.relu(local)

       out = tf.add(tf.matmul(local_out, w_out), b_out)
       return out

   model_op = model()

   cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(model_op, y))
   train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

   correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(model_op, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
   accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
       onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 2, on_value=1.,off_value=0.,axis=-1)
       onehot_vals = sess.run(onehot_labels)
       batch_size = len(data)
       # Restore model
       saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\\Testing\\mymodel.meta')
       saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
       all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars')
       for v in all_vars:
           v_ = sess.run(v)
           print(v_)

   for j in range(0, 5):
       print('EPOCH', j)
       for i in range(0, len(data), batch_size):
           batch_data = data[i:i+batch_size, :]
           batch_onehot_vals = onehot_vals[i:i+batch_size, :]
           _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_data, y: batch_onehot_vals})
           print(i, accuracy_val)

       print('DONE WITH EPOCH')
   ```

**EDIT 1**

Would restoring this way work?

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('C:\\Users\\Abder-Rahman\\Desktop\\\Testing\\mymodel.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
print('model restored'
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how I **save** my model:

```
#Save model
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saved_path = saver.save(sess, 'C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\\Testing\\mymodel')
print("The model is in this file: ", saved_path)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your saver code was correct. 
While variables must add to collections before retrieving the collection.

`tf.add_to_collection("vars", w1)
tf.add_to_collection("vars", b1)
...`

Then
 `all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars')`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Also, it is not necessary to have code that saves the model in the code above where I just want to *restore* the model, right?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I restore a TensorFlow model like this:

```
 with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    if os.path.exists(save_path):
        # Restore variables from disk.
        saver.restore(session, save_path)
    else:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        print('Initialized')

    # do the work
    # ... 
 saver.save(session, save_path)   # save the model
```

example code can be fetch [here](https://github.com/ahangchen/GDLnotes/blob/ec8d5579f1e3c6e64912d51792391da6e287a52c/src/convnet/hyper_conv_mnist.py).

I need to know more about how you save your model, it seems that your model was restored before save, and your model didn't turn to a tf.graph and connect with the session.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have added how I *save* my model under **EDIT 2** in my question. I thought that I need to once save the model and then restore it separately. In other words, when I *train* my model, I *save*. After that, when I want to *test* the model,  I *restore*. Am I correct here?

Comment: @Simplicity you only need to save your model if you want to do something(training or testing) after the python process ends up, or you can share the model in memory in both training and testing

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have read my blog [here](https://wordpress.com/stats/post/541/kevincodeidea.wordpress.com) , the mechanism for model saving is quite straightforward, when you load a model, the parameter values and relations (which are probably all you care about) are matched by variable name.

For example

```
#simplesave.py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:#yes you have to have a graph first
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    b = tf.Variable(1.0, name="bias")
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,'model') #b should be saved in the model file

#simpleload.py

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    #still need the definition, again
    b = tf.Variable(0.0, name="bias")
    saver = tf.train.Saver() #now it is satisfied...
    saver.restore(sess,model)
```

What confused me here is, you used a function `all_vars = tf.get_collection('vars')`, but you have never defined a scope called "vars". You probably should test using `tf.all_variables()`first.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. When I removed "vars", I got the following error: TypeError: get_collection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'. If I restore the model simply as shown in **EDIT 2**, would that work?